# Update Node.js: Error while updating to stable version

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

trying to upadate node version.
R[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ9jy.jpg)unning this sequence of commands.

1.npm cache clean -f

2. npm install -g n

after running the second command I am getting this error

$ npm install -g n
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@9.0.0: wanted {"os":"!win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32

npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any

npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32

npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shara\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-09-10T16_40_44_122Z-debug.log

Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

https://nodejs.org/en/

If you visit this official node.js website, you can download the latest version  depending on your operating system.
You will be able to successfully upgrade your node version this way

Comment: Thankyou axit-vadi. Would i have to delete the current version i have?

Comment: Sharazer, you do not need to delete your old version of node js, only install the new version. Check the box that says install necessary packages for node during the installation process. Then it will open Powershell and install all the necessary packages.
The installation of the package takes some time. After successful installation, type the following
node --version
 Version check command in CMD